# Any tips on creating a Dragon/Eagle Head?

Tags: modeling

I have been using blender for about 2 1/2 years now, and I wanted to get some more in depth experience in animation!

I figured I needed a cool looking character.

I am basing the design off of a drawing I did a while back, so I want to make it look similar.

I realized that there is probably more than one good technique for creating dragon heads.

If you have any advice on this project, let me know!

This is my model so far:

[image: my model of a dragon like beast for a big project i am working on]

Comment: see more blender modelling tutorials and thats it, and also depends in the design of the dragon that you want to make...which its the dragon that you are looking to make?